# mac easy_install problem

Tags: python, macos

I've tried to install a python package using easy_install. I used the easy_install from /usr/local/bin as I thought that was the one supplied by macpython. I've encountered this problem:

```
ValueError: numpy >= 1.4 is required (detected 1.2.1 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/numpy/__init__.pyc)
```

It seems like when checking for dependencies, easy_install is looking at the directory pointed by python that was shipped with Mac.

How can I alter this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `virtualenv` with `--no-site-packages` then install your package into there.  You might also want to investigate `pip` instead of `easy_install`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a different version of python from the system supplied one,
find the framework bin directory for that version, for example:

```
$ ls -l $(which python2.7)
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  71 Jul 13  2010 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
```

Then run the version of easy_install that is in that directory:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/easy_install
```